Ajax call not happening in microsoft team login popup using external SAML Identity
I have an on-premise SAML2.0 Identity provider. Login page of this identity provider, calling an Ajax call to localhost server. You can assume that on every user machine, a localhost server will listen incoming traffic.
When user is try to login using chrome/edge, I am getting breakpoint at localhost API and everything is working as expected.
When i trying to login into microsoft team desktop app, after entering  email id, microsoft redirects me to my SAML identity provider login page and ajax call triggered. but there is no call to localhost API.
I have added CORS in localhost API call and SAML identity domain name added in allow-origin.
Below one is ajax call:
 $.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost/auth",
    type: 'GET',
    success: successCb,
    crossDomain:true,
    error: function (xhr, exe) {
        window.location.href = 'https://parent.abc.com/sso/mobile/auth/showerror1?status=' + xhr.status + '&error='+exe;
    }
});

In above ajax, when trying to login from browser, successCb is fired but with microsoft login popup, always Error is executed.
Not able to understand what is going wrong here.
Complete details are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1689092/login-not-working-into-desktop-team-app-from-exter

